# Android App Sometimes Crashing Sometimes not

Tags: android, crash

I just want to ask why is my app is crashing and stopped sometimes when i'm processing data's or clicking my button in my app.
I just try it earlier and its ok but now it start crashing and says " Unfortunately, Apps has Stopped! ".

can anyone know what is the reason of it?

This is the one that appear in my logcat:

```
03-25 16:29:38.795: I/Process(737): Sending signal. PID: 737 SIG: 9
03-25 16:29:38.805: I/WindowState(277): WIN DEATH: Window{40f63440 u0 com.say.saintmichael/com.say.saintmichael.MakeASchedule}
03-25 16:29:38.815: I/ActivityManager(277): Process com.say.saintmichael (pid 737) has died.
03-25 16:29:38.815: I/jdwp(653): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:38.825: I/WindowState(277): WIN DEATH: Window{4106da48 u0 com.say.saintmichael/com.say.saintmichael.MainActivity}
03-25 16:29:38.825: I/jdwp(442): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:38.845: I/jdwp(414): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:38.855: I/jdwp(582): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:38.865: I/jdwp(277): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:38.875: D/dalvikvm(809): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-25 16:29:38.885: I/jdwp(402): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:38.885: I/ActivityManager(277): Start proc com.say.saintmichael for activity com.say.saintmichael/.MainActivity: pid=809 uid=10049 gids={50049, 3003, 1028}
03-25 16:29:38.905: I/jdwp(554): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:38.915: I/jdwp(499): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:38.935: I/Choreographer(277): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 16:29:38.955: I/Choreographer(277): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 16:29:38.965: I/jdwp(361): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:38.975: I/jdwp(389): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:38.988: I/jdwp(600): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.065: I/jdwp(678): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.135: I/jdwp(277): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.145: I/jdwp(402): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.157: I/jdwp(554): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.165: I/jdwp(499): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.175: I/jdwp(600): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.195: I/jdwp(361): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.215: I/jdwp(389): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.225: I/Choreographer(277): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 16:29:39.235: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-25 16:29:39.255: I/jdwp(809): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.255: I/jdwp(463): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.315: I/jdwp(635): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.375: I/jdwp(533): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.415: I/jdwp(515): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.475: E/Trace(809): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-25 16:29:39.475: I/jdwp(442): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.495: I/jdwp(653): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
03-25 16:29:39.785: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 117K, 9% free 2662K/2900K, paused 72ms+12ms, total 153ms
03-25 16:29:39.925: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-25 16:29:39.975: W/InputMethodManagerService(277): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 737 uid 10049
03-25 16:29:39.995: D/gralloc_goldfish(809): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-25 16:29:40.085: I/ActivityManager(277): Displayed com.say.saintmichael/.MainActivity: +1s245ms (total +1m33s495ms)
03-25 16:29:40.135: I/ActivityManager(277): START u0 {cmp=com.say.saintmichael/.MakeASchedule} from pid 809
03-25 16:29:40.135: W/WindowManager(277): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21015
03-25 16:29:40.565: I/Choreographer(809): Skipped 104 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 16:29:40.915: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-25 16:29:41.125: I/ActivityManager(277): Displayed com.say.saintmichael/.MakeASchedule: +853ms
03-25 16:29:47.904: I/ActivityManager(277): START u0 {cmp=com.say.saintmichael/.Wedding_Reservation} from pid 809
03-25 16:29:47.914: W/WindowManager(277): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21015
03-25 16:29:48.104: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37K, 6% free 2901K/3060K, paused 22ms, total 28ms
03-25 16:29:48.114: I/dalvikvm-heap(809): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.554MB for 635812-byte allocation
03-25 16:29:48.224: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 3520K/3684K, paused 108ms, total 108ms
03-25 16:29:48.454: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 5% free 3527K/3684K, paused 71ms+101ms, total 235ms
03-25 16:29:48.974: E/Cus ID(809): 4
03-25 16:29:48.974: E/SQLiteLog(809): (1) no such column: reg_date
03-25 16:29:48.984: D/AndroidRuntime(809): Shutting down VM
03-25 16:29:48.994: W/dalvikvm(809): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.say.saintmichael/com.say.saintmichael.Wedding_Reservation}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: reg_date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, firstname, middlename, lastname, email, age, gender, username, password, barangay, com_address, reg_date, bd_month, bd_date, bd_year, cus_id FROM tblcustomer WHERE username = 'lawlaw'
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: reg_date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, firstname, middlename, lastname, email, age, gender, username, password, barangay, com_address, reg_date, bd_month, bd_date, bd_year, cus_id FROM tblcustomer WHERE username = 'lawlaw'
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.say.saintmichael.db.DBHelper.getAllCustomerInfo(DBHelper.java:180)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.say.saintmichael.Wedding_Reservation.initControls(Wedding_Reservation.java:223)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.say.saintmichael.Wedding_Reservation.onCreate(Wedding_Reservation.java:152)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-25 16:29:49.144: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  ... 11 more
03-25 16:29:49.284: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 91K, 6% free 3884K/4096K, paused 69ms+121ms, total 275ms
03-25 16:29:49.304: W/ActivityManager(277):   Force finishing activity com.say.saintmichael/.Wedding_Reservation
03-25 16:29:49.314: W/ActivityManager(277):   Force finishing activity com.say.saintmichael/.MakeASchedule
03-25 16:29:49.594: I/Choreographer(277): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 16:29:49.604: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-25 16:29:49.844: W/ActivityManager(277): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41227cb8 u0 com.say.saintmichael/.Wedding_Reservation}
03-25 16:29:50.094: D/dalvikvm(277): GC_CONCURRENT freed 769K, 15% free 6916K/8080K, paused 76ms+38ms, total 332ms
03-25 16:29:57.932: W/ActivityManager(277): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
03-25 16:29:57.935: W/ActivityManager(277): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{41227cb8 u0 com.say.saintmichael/.Wedding_Reservation}
03-25 16:29:59.935: W/ActivityManager(277): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{40eae4b0 u0 com.say.saintmichael/.MainActivity}
03-25 16:30:08.003: W/ActivityManager(277): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{40f2d348 u0 com.say.saintmichael/.MakeASchedule}
03-25 16:30:08.004: W/ActivityManager(277): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{41227cb8 u0 com.say.saintmichael/.Wedding_Reservation}
03-25 16:30:12.680: D/ExchangeService(635): Received deviceId from Email app: null
03-25 16:30:12.680: D/ExchangeService(635): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
03-25 16:30:17.725: D/ExchangeService(635): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
03-25 16:30:17.734: W/ActivityManager(277): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-25 16:30:17.734: D/ExchangeService(635): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
03-25 16:30:17.744: W/ActivityManager(277): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf88f8 that was originally bound here
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf88f8 that was originally bound here
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-25 16:30:17.754: E/ActivityThread(635):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635): null
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf88f8 that was originally bound here
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-25 16:30:17.844: E/StrictMode(635):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-25 16:30:17.844: W/ActivityManager(277): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40fd0d78
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf8530 that was originally bound here
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf8530 that was originally bound here
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-25 16:30:17.854: E/ActivityThread(635):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635): null
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf8530 that was originally bound here
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-25 16:30:17.874: E/StrictMode(635):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-25 16:30:17.884: D/dalvikvm(635): GC_CONCURRENT freed 469K, 20% free 2465K/3056K, paused 73ms+4ms, total 119ms
03-25 16:30:17.884: W/ActivityManager(277): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40fd0ae8
03-25 16:31:02.817: D/ExchangeService(635): Received deviceId from Email app: null
03-25 16:31:02.817: D/ExchangeService(635): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
03-25 16:31:07.885: D/ExchangeService(635): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
03-25 16:31:07.885: W/ActivityManager(277): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-25 16:31:07.885: D/ExchangeService(635): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
03-25 16:31:07.905: W/ActivityManager(277): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
```

Comment: look at the logcat and check the stacktrace

Comment: Are you doing the data processing on the UI thread?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are sending the wrong database query.

From stacktrace:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: **no such column: reg_date** (code 1): , 
while compiling: 
SELECT _id, firstname, middlename, lastname, email, age, gender, username, password, barangay, com_address, reg_date, bd_month, bd_date, bd_year, cus_id FROM tblcustomer WHERE username = 'lawlaw'